# Jquery script doen't load in a logical order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code here in a JS file, where I've put two `console.log()`, one at the beginning and one at the end, to see why I'm having problems targeting the with a specific ID / class. Now I see that the `console.log()` at the end loads before the one in the beginning. Even when I place a `console.log()` outside of the file underneath the `<script>` tag which loads this JS file, it loads before the JS file, which doesn't make any sense to me. How can I fix this problem?

```
/*!
 * jquery.instagramFeed
 *
 * @version 1.2.7
 *
 * @author Javier Sanahuja Liebana <bannss1@gmail.com>
 * @contributor csanahuja <csanahuja10@gmail.com>
 *
 * https://github.com/jsanahuja/jquery.instagramFeed
 *
 */
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        'host': "https://www.instagram.com/",
        'username': 'username',
        'tag': '',
        'container': '#instagram',
        'display_profile': true,
        'display_biography': true,
        'display_gallery': true,
        'display_igtv': false,
        'get_data': false,
        'callback': null,
        'styling': true,
        'items': 8,
        'items_per_row': 4,
        'margin': 0.5,
        'image_size': 640
    };
    var image_sizes = {
        "150": 0,
        "240": 1,
        "320": 2,
        "480": 3,
        "640": 4
    };
    var escape_map = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;',
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#39;',
        '/': '&#x2F;',
        '`': '&#x60;',
        '=': '&#x3D;'
    };
    function escape_string(str){
        return str.replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function (char) {
            return escape_map[char];
        });
    }

    $.instagramFeed = function(opts){


      //console log at the beginning of the function
      console.log("Beginning instagramFeed");



        var options = $.fn.extend({}, defaults, opts);
        if(options.username == "" && options.tag == ""){
            console.error("Instagram Feed: Error, no username or tag found.");
            return false;
        }
        if(typeof options.get_raw_json !== "undefined"){
            console.warn("Instagram Feed: get_raw_json is deprecated. See use get_data instead");
            options.get_data = options.get_raw_json;
        }
        if(!options.get_data && options.container == ""){
            console.error("Instagram Feed: Error, no container found.");
            return false;
        }
        if(options.get_data && options.callback == null){
            console.error("Instagram Feed: Error, no callback defined to get the raw json");
            return false;
        }

        var is_tag = options.username == "",
            url = is_tag ? options.host + "explore/tags/"+ options.tag + "/" : options.host + options.username + "/";

        $.get(url, function(data){
            try{
                data = data.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split("<\/script>")[0];
            }catch(e){
                console.error("Instagram Feed: It looks like the profile you are trying to fetch is age restricted. See https://github.com/jsanahuja/InstagramFeed/issues/26");
                return;
            }
            data = JSON.parse(data.substr(0, data.length - 1));
            data = data.entry_data.ProfilePage || data.entry_data.TagPage;
            if(typeof data === "undefined"){
                console.error("Instagram Feed: It looks like YOUR network has been temporary banned because of too many requests. See https://github.com/jsanahuja/jquery.instagramFeed/issues/25");
                return;
            }
            data = data[0].graphql.user || data[0].graphql.hashtag;

            if(options.get_data){
                options.callback(data);
                return;
            }   

            //Setting styles
            var styles = {
                'profile_container': "",
                'profile_image': "",
                'profile_name': "",
                'profile_biography': "",
                'gallery_image': ""
            };
            if(options.styling){
                styles.profile_container = " style='text-align:center;'";
                styles.profile_image = " style='border-radius:10em;width:15%;max-width:125px;min-width:50px;'";
                styles.profile_name = " style='font-size:1.2em;'";
                styles.profile_biography = " style='font-size:1em;'";
                var width = (100 - options.margin * 2 * options.items_per_row)/options.items_per_row;
                styles.gallery_image = " style='margin:"+options.margin+"% "+options.margin+"%;width:"+width+"%;float:left;'";
            }

            var html = "";
            //Displaying profile
            if(options.display_profile){
                html += "<div class='instagram_profile'" +styles.profile_container +">";
                html += "<img class='instagram_profile_image' src='"+ data.profile_pic_url +"' alt='"+ (is_tag ? data.name + " tag pic" : data.username + " profile pic") +"'"+ styles.profile_image +" />";
                if(is_tag)
                    html += "<p class='instagram_tag'"+ styles.profile_name +"><a href='https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+ options.tag +"' rel='noopener' target='_blank'>#"+ options.tag +"</a></p>";
                else
                    html += "<p class='instagram_username'"+ styles.profile_name +">@"+ data.full_name +" (<a href='https://www.instagram.com/"+ options.username +"' rel='noopener' target='_blank'>@"+options.username+"</a>)</p>";

                if(!is_tag && options.display_biography)
                    html += "<p class='instagram_biography'"+ styles.profile_biography +">"+ data.biography +"</p>";

                html += "</div>";
            }

            //image size
            var image_index = typeof image_sizes[options.image_size] !== "undefined" ? image_sizes[options.image_size] : image_sizes[640];

            if(options.display_gallery){
                if(typeof data.is_private !== "undefined" && data.is_private === true){
                    html += "<p class='instagram_private'><strong>This profile is private</strong></p>";
                }else{
                    var imgs = (data.edge_owner_to_timeline_media || data.edge_hashtag_to_media).edges;
                        max = (imgs.length > options.items) ? options.items : imgs.length;

                    html += "<div class='instagram_gallery'>";
                    for(var i = 0; i < max; i++){
                        var url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + imgs[i].node.shortcode,
                            image, type_resource, caption, date, likes, comments;


                        switch(imgs[i].node.__typename){
                            case "GraphSidecar":
                                type_resource = "sidecar"
                                image = imgs[i].node.thumbnail_resources[image_index].src;
                                date = new Date(imgs[i].node.taken_at_timestamp * 1000);
                                likes = imgs[i].node.edge_media_preview_like.count;
                                comments = imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_comment.count;
                                break;
                            case "GraphVideo":
                                type_resource = "video";
                                image = imgs[i].node.thumbnail_src
                                break;
                            default:
                                type_resource = "image";
                                image = imgs[i].node.thumbnail_resources[image_index].src;
                                date = new Date(imgs[i].node.taken_at_timestamp * 1000);
                                likes = imgs[i].node.edge_media_preview_like.count;
                                comments = imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_comment.count;
                        }
                                console.log(date);
                                console.log(likes);
                                console.log(comments);

                        if(
                            typeof imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0] !== "undefined" && 
                            typeof imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node !== "undefined" && 
                            typeof imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text !== "undefined" && 
                            imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text !== null
                        ){
                            caption = imgs[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text;
                        }else if(
                            typeof imgs[i].node.accessibility_caption !== "undefined" && 
                            imgs[i].node.accessibility_caption !== null
                        ){
                            caption = imgs[i].node.accessibility_caption;
                        }else{
                            caption = (is_tag ? data.name : data.username) + " image " + i;
                        }

                        html += "<a id='instagramID" + i + "' class='instagramimg instagram-" + type_resource + "' rel='noopener' target='_blank'>";
                        html += "<img class='instagramicon' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0278/9644/7113/files/instagram-icon.svg?v=1592246117' alt='instagramicon'>";
                        html += "<div class='instagramhover'></div>";
                        html += "<img src='" + image + "' alt='" + escape_string(caption) + "'"/* + styles.gallery_image*/ +" />";
                        html += "</a>";
                    }

                  }
                }


            if(options.display_igtv && typeof data.edge_felix_video_timeline !== "undefined"){
                var igtv = data.edge_felix_video_timeline.edges,
                    max = (igtv.length > options.items) ? options.items : igtv.length
                if(igtv.length > 0){
                    html += "<div class='instagram_igtv'>";
                    for(var i = 0; i < max; i++){
                        html += "<a href='https://www.instagram.com/p/"+ igtv[i].node.shortcode +"' rel='noopener' target='_blank'>";
                        html += "<img src='"+ igtv[i].node.thumbnail_src +"' alt='"+ options.username +" instagram image "+ i+"'"+styles.gallery_image+" />";
                        html += "</a>";
                    }
                    html += "</div>";
                }
            }

            $(options.container).html(html);
        }).fail(function(e){
            console.error("Instagram Feed: Unable to fetch the given user/tag. Instagram responded with the status code: ", e.status);
        });

        return true;
    };


  // Ending of the code
  console.log("Ending instagramFeed");



})(jQuery);
```

This function gets called like this in the html part. Also here, the `console.log("before instagramFeed.JS");` loads together with `console.log("after instagramFeed.JS");`, and after that I receive the

```
    console.log(date);
    console.log(likes);
    console.log(comments);
```

which are inside the for loop of the function.

```
<script src="{{ 'jquery.instagramFeed.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
      <div id="instagram"></div> 
      <script>
        console.log("before instagramFeed.JS");
          (function($){
              $(window).on('load', function(){
                  $.instagramFeed({
                      'username': 'username',
                      'container': "#instagram",
                      'display_profile': false,
                      'display_biography': false,
                      'display_gallery': true,
                      'callback': null,
                      'styling': true,
                      'items': 10,
                      'items_per_row': 5,
                      'margin': 0.2 
                  });
              });
          })(jQuery);
        console.log("after instagramFeed.JS");
      </script>
```

Comment: `Ending instagramFeed` statement is located outside `instagramFeed` function AFAIS.

Comment: I added the console.log inside of the function, and still it loads before the output of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executed in the following order:

- first snippet (definition of `instagramFeed` plugin) is executed **during** page load. `console.log` statements outside of that plugin are executed as well.
- window is loaded (all `script` tag contents are read and executed), your window load handler kicks in. It calls your `instagramFeed` function the way you set it in the second snippet. `before/after instagramFeed.JS` logs are executed here. `instagramFeed` function starts a network call the result of which is processed after the load handler finishes running.
- network call response is processed. comments, likes and date are logged at this stage.

As a result, everything is working as expected if I understand the purpose correctly.

**UPD**: to use the elements generated by network call response handler (provided you have an opportunity to edit the plugin code directly) you can add a function into `options` object, say `onImageElementsCreated` and call it after the loop in the plugin. Then you can provide your function as another option in the second snippet.

Comment: Okay, so how can I call another function, but only after the for loop has been completed? Since the for loop creates html elements which I need to access with `getElementById` I can only access these elements when the for loop is completed and the elements have been created.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this with 100% certainty, as I haven't run the code.
However, I think the line console.log("Ending instagramFeed"); is being run before the line console.log("Beginning instagramFeed");, because it's outside the function $.instagramFeed = function(opts).

The function is created, then the ending log line is called, then something is calling the function, then the beginning log line is called.

Where in your code do you call $.instagramFeed()?

Comment: I added the code which loads the function inside HTML. Also when I add the `console.log("Ending instagramFeed");` inside of the function, it loads both consolelogs (first the beginning, than the ending) and after this I get the consolelogs outside of the for loop.